Ethers can't find method of smart contract
I get that error when I try call method of contract:
contract.GetOptions is not a function
TypeError: contract.GetOptions is not a function

Although contract.interface.fragments show the GetOptions method
Here is a code:
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import VoteContract from "./abi.json"

import { abi } from "./abi"

export default async function getContract(contractAddress) {
  const ethereum = (window).ethereum;
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_requestAccounts",
  });

  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum)
  const walletAddress = accounts[0]    // first account in MetaMask
  const signer = provider.getSigner(walletAddress)

  await provider.send("wallet_addEthereumChain", [
    {
      chainId: "0x539",
      chainName: "localhost",
      nativeCurrency: {
        name: "ETH",
        symbol: "ETH",
        decimals: 9,
      },
      rpcUrls: ["http://127.0.0.1:8545/"],
    },
  ]);

  await provider.send("wallet_switchEthereumChain", [
    { chainId: "0x539" },
  ]);

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    abi,
    provider
  );

  console.log(contract.interface.fragments)
  console.log(contract.GetOptions())

  return contract;
}


I already tried to pass provider and signer to Contract

I know nothing from Ethers, but https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/ the docs for this class doesn't tells anything about this method. Probably it really doesn't exists. You can try using "getOptions" instead, as it's a common style of writing, but it would probably not work

Seems like your abi JSON doesn't contain definition of the GetOptions function or is incorrectly formatted. Can you edit the question and post the full abi contents as well?
